# Spring data JPA/Hibernate - Is there a way to mark an entity field as transient dynamically at runtime?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a database that is being upgraded to add a column to an existing table. However, I would like to make the Springboot service backwards compatible with the older version. I would like to mark the entity field as transient for older versions to avoid persisting the value, avoiding any errors. The database itself stores the version - the service just needs to check the database to determine whether the field should be transient and mark it as such. Is there a Spring Data JPA/Hibernate API that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible, but why would you even want to do that? IMO an application should upgrade the schema prior or during deployment to the latest state that it expects.

Comment: You're correct, it would be better to do what you're suggesting. However, for backward-compatibility, the code needs to handle versions of the database with and without the column, which it will only know upon startup.

Comment: If you want to support the old schema, deploy the old application. Once you update the schema, deploy the new version.

Comment: Ya what you're saying makes sense, the problem is the newer code needs to support the old schema as well. It's not the most desirable situation.

Comment: Then model your app against the old schema until all databases have the new schema. The new schema must be backwards compatible though i.e. use triggers to fill new columns. Then, you can switch to the new schema in your app and as soon as the new app version is deployed everywhere, you can drop the triggers.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't force all databases to upgrade. That's where the trickiness lies.